# Azure pipeline does't allow to git push throwing 'GenericContribute' permission is needed

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying push some changes done during Azure pipeline using `cmd` component as follows,

```
steps:
- script: |
   git config user.email you@you.com
   git config user.name "your name"
   git diff
   git  add .
   git commit -m "version update [skip ci]"
   git push origin HEAD:master
```

But it fails showing following error.

> remote: 0000000000aaTF41027: You need the Git 'GenericContribute'
>   permission to perform this action. Details: identity
>   'Build\sdfdfjjkk', scope 'repository'

I already set the necessary permission as follows:

[image]

And the `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` is also enabled as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365812/push-to-local-azure-devops-git-from-build-pipeline)

What other permissions do I need to give this to work?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to grant the permissions to **Project Collection Build Service (account name)**:

[image]

Answer (score 111):

If you get the following error in your build...

> TF401027: You need the Git ‘GenericContribute’ permission to perform
> this action. Details: identity

...then, to fix it:

1. Copy the guid part of the identity name from the error message
2. Go to the repository settings
3. Paste the guid into the permissions search box for user or group.
4. This will then display a “Project Collection Build Service (OrganisationName)”. Select that user
5. Set the permissions as stated in other answers.

Comment: upvote this!!! 

Comment: This was the missing piece, i was giving the permission to the group but it was required on the user (or the build use isn't in the group)

Comment: +1 This was also the last bit for me.. Specially because there are other shown "Build service" users and the important one only shows up after searching with the GUID. Just to add, you need to do the search in the specific repository, not on the "all repositories" section.

Comment: Additionally setting `git config --global user.email $BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL` and `git config --global user.name "$BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR"` before interacting with git is useful in combination with this answer.

Answer (score 37):

It should caused by your account do not have the **contribute** permission for this repository.

Go **Project setting** --> **Repositories** --> click **Repos** you want to operate -->set repository permissions accordingly.

[image]

Comment: There isn't a "Project Collection Build Service (???)" user - how come?  I set the permissions on the "Project Collection Build Service Accounts" but that didn't do it.. https://imgur.com/0zBsIew  thanks

Comment: @dan, "Project Collection Build Service (xxx)", this is the identity which exist in project.You can add it in it with the "Add" button, and search "Project Collection Build Service (xxx)"(user, not group). The reason that no work to set permission on "Project Collection Build Service Accounts" for you, is you may did not add this user(Project Collection Build Service(xxx)) into this group. You can check this under your Org setting-->Permissions.

Comment: Follow this answer - worked for me. Secret is to copy the user UUID from the error message and paste it into the 'Search' box - it reveals a user that is not shown on the page by default. Then just add Contribute permissions.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55995046/923410

Answer (score 0):

**Even if you have permission but still not able to push the code. Please follow the below steps.**

- Please check if you have a valid ***user*** and ***password*** configured in ***git***. If not follow the below steps.
- Go to Repository and create a personnel access token which you will use as a password for committing and pushing the code to repos along with your username.

*So the best way you can configure your URL while doing the clone.*

**GitLab Example :**

```
GitLab URL for clone: 

https://gitlab.com/myrepo/demoProject.git

GitLab configured URL for clone:

https://username:accessToken@gitlab.com/myrepo/demoProject.git. // Follow this approach to clone
```

**Azure Example :**

```
Azure URL for clone: 

https://MY-ORG@dev.azure.com/MY-ORG/MyRepo/_git/demo

Azure configured URL for clone:

https://username:accessToken@dev.azure.com/MY-ORG/MyRepo/_git/demo // Follow this approach to clone
```

**Once you are able to clone these repos then you are all set to commit and push your code.**

That’s all. It will save your day!!