# Cannot push git tags in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently experiencing a problem that is really puzzling me. I want to tag a git commit via an Azure Devops build pipeline. I followed this tutorial: https://elanderson.net/2020/04/azure-devops-pipelines-manual-tagging/ and the only thing that I am diverging in is the use of bash instead of PowerShell. (I tried with PowerShell too, but I got the same error)

The error I am getting is this:

[image]

My build definition is here

```yaml
variables:
  BuildConfiguration: release
  BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'

stages:
  - stage: DeployArtifacts
    jobs:
   
    - job: TagSources
      displayName: 'Tag Sources'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        persistCredentials: true
        clean: true
        fetchDepth: 1

      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          failOnStderr: false
          script: |                        
            #pwd
            #ls -alR
            Version="1.00"
            echo "Tagging branch with $Version"
            git tag $(Version)
            echo "Successfully tagged branch"
            git push --tags
            echo "Pushed tag to branch $Version"
```

I also added the contribute permissions to the build account as suggested in this post ([Azure pipeline does't allow to git push throwing 'GenericContribute' permission is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541458/azure-pipeline-doest-allow-to-git-push-throwing-genericcontribute-permission)) but I still get the same error. I am not sure what else I can try.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue in the meanwhile myself. It is not very pretty but it works.
I commented out `persistCredentials: true` and added the PAT in the origin of the git repository.

```
        # Fix as persistCredentials is not returning the desired result
        REMOTE_NAME=$(git remote get-url origin)
        echo "Remote name: $REMOTE_NAME"
        NEW_REMOTE="${REMOTE_NAME//https:\/\/XXXXX@/https:\/\/XXXXX:$(PAT)@}"
        echo "New Remote name: $NEW_REMOTE"
        git remote set-url origin $NEW_REMOTE
```

Push now works without any issues.

I am not sure why the proposed changes do not work in my Azure Devops account.
Thanks for the help and answers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any specific rule on which branches/commits to tag, you can set the pipeline to add Tag automatically upon completing the build

[image: Add Tag automatically]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think for most people this may work but I just copied a snippet of my yaml file. (the complete pipeline is nearly 500 lines) I am getting the variable dynamically from some piece of code reading a file. That's why I think this won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you choose the wrong repo's security settings. Or you could set the security settings for all Repositories under **Project Settings**--> **Repositories**.

[image]

**Besides**, check if your current account is under **Platform Build Service** group. And you could also add your current account there and set all the permission for your account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that already I assigned contribute permission to both service accounts for all repositories. My account has administrator permissions in the project.