# How to automatically version npm package in Azure DevOps (without triggering new pipeline)?

Tags: npm, azure-devops, semantic-versioning

#### What we're trying to do

We are using Azure Pipelines (`azure-pipelines.yml`) to automate ci/cd. Part of our configuration completes the versioning of our project for publishing to Azure Artifacts. We're also trying to configure this to update the existing version number in `package.json` without triggering a new pipeline in Azure DevOps.

This is the relevant section for our `azure-pipelines.yml` file:

```
  - script: |
      git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
      git config --global user.name "User name"
      npm version patch -m "Bump version to %s [skip ci]" --force
    displayName: 'Bump release version'
  - script: |
      npm pack
    displayName: 'Package package'
```

This works well to publish the package to our Azure Artifacts feed, but does not update the existing version in `package.json`

Our `package.json` contains the following:

```
"release": {
    "plugins": [
        "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
        "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
        "@semantic-release/changelog",
        [
            "@semantic-release/npm",
            {
                "npmPublish": false
            }
        ],
        [
            "@semantic-release/git",
            {
                "assets": [
                    "dist/",
                    "package.json",
                    "CHANGELOG.md"
                ],
                "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

#### Question

How would we update the script to ensure the `version` value in `package.json` is also updated without triggering another pipeline execution (which would result in an endless loop of triggering new pipeline executions)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another script task to push back to your devops git repo. But firstly, you need to add [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) step and set the **persistCredentials** to true to authenticate the git command. See below example:

```
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |

   git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
   git config --global user.name "User name"
   npm version patch -m "Bump version to %s [skip ci]" --force

  displayName: 'Bump release version'

- script: |

   git push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName)

  displayName: 'Update Git Repo'
```

Since you have **[skip ci]** in the commit message. Push back the updated package.json file will not trigger a new build. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-do-i-avoid-triggering-a-ci-build-when-the-script-pushes).

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. For anyone getting a `GenericContribute` error, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541458/azure-pipeline-doest-allow-to-git-push-throwing-genericcontribute-permission). If you still can't get it to work, copy the uid `Build/<uid>` part in the error and paste it into the user field on the security tab as the answer in the other question suggests + set appropriate permissions as the answer mentions.