# Script that will merge changes from the master to my branch

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to write a script that will merge changes from the master to my branch that will be built in Azure DevOps

```sh
git config –global user.email "My Email"
git config –global user.name "My User Name"
REPO="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(Build.Repository.Name)"
EXTRAHEADER="Authorization: Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
git -c http.extraheader="$EXTRAHEADER" clone $REPO
cd $(Build.Repository.Name)
# ls


git config http.$REPO.extraHeader "$EXTRAHEADER"
              
git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
git status
ls -la
git merge --no-ff --no-edit origin/automatecitest
ls -la
```

I have configured the rights that are described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).
but I am getting errors

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <vsts@fv.fx.internal.cloudapp.net>) not allowed
```

Could you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly what the error message suggests, i.e., telling Git what author and committer name and email address to use for new commits? In general, though, it's unwise to completely automate merging, because some merges *fail*.

Comment: @torek "*…telling Git what author and committer name and email address to use…*" The first two lines of the script; wrong kind of dash there.

Comment: @phd: oops, I skimmed right over those somehow (probably because the OP didn't show any error output from those two commands, even though they do produce errors). And yes, the text in the question has en-dashes instead of double hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your actual script, you are merging `origin/automatecitest` to `main`.

I archive via below code:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: Ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: none

- script: |
    REPO="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(Build.Repository.Name)"
    git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" $REPO
    cd $(Build.Repository.Name)
    ls
    git config user.email "tester1@hotmail.com"
    git config user.name "tester1"
    git merge --no-ff --no-edit origin/automatecitest
    ls -la
```

I enabled in project setting:
[image]

[image]

Note:

1. You can change the branch, from main to other..
2. The change will not push back to main branch since you need to add extra step to push. if you cat file change afte merge in the task, you can see the merge result.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I merge my branch but I can't make a push command
I added 
 - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
```
echo GIT PUSH
git push https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/repo $(Build.SourceBranchName)```

error
GIT PUSH
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/repo $(Build.SourceBranchName)```'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml assigned the rights as in the article

Comment: you have used 'persistCredentials: true', then you can directly push the code, no need to  use system.accesstoken. Remember to grant repository permission for `Project Collection Build Service (account name)'. Please refer to link for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541458/azure-pipeline-doest-allow-to-git-push-throwing-genericcontribute-permission

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko, how is it going? would you please mark my reply as answer if it helps? let me know if you have any queries. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @wadezhou, yes, everything worked, thanks so much)